# Is there another name for this "power of two" sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was recently asked how to call a number sequence, and since I am not sure about naming conventions, I am grateful for any help.

There is a sequence of real numbers, where:

- the next element always equals the previous element, multiplied by 2
- 1 is included

A slice of this sequence will look like that: 0.0625, 0.125, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32.

Is there a well-known name for this sequence? I see powers of two, starting from 1, but is there a name like “integers” or “Fibonacci numbers”?

Are there separate names for an integer part and fractional part?
I saw [several names](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+2%2C+4%2C+8%2C+16%2C+32&sort=&language=&go=Search) in [OEIS](https://oeis.org/), but what about fractional part?

Comment: The numbers on the left (less than $1$) are negative powers of $2$

Comment: That's a geometric sequence with coefficient $q=2$ & first term $a_1=0.0625$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is called a [geometric progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) of common ratio 2. The first element of the sequence is the *scale factor*.